# Selenium Webdriver - How to use Robot Framework with Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to use robot framework with java in Eclipse IDE. i have installed robot framework in Eclipse IDE. How to write script by using robot framework with Selenium web-driver.

Comment: Have you followed the official installation instructions? http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/Installation and https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library#installation

Comment: Yeah but these links explain work with Python etc but i have to work java. How to write scripts in java by using Robot framework?

Comment: its not very clear, please provide me any other help.

Comment: "how to write scripts in java by using robot framework" makes no sense. Robot is not a tool for writing java. Robot is a tool for executing test.  Are you asking how to write _keywords_ in java?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use eclipse as an IDE to write your tests you can use this plugin:

[RobotFramework-EclipseIDE](https://github.com/NitorCreations/RobotFramework-EclipseIDE/wiki)

If your goal is to write a java method then call it from robotframework you can use [Remote library](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/RemoteLibrary).

Here are the supported formats writing robotium tests:
[Robotium Test Data Sytntax](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.1#test-data-syntax)

You can also use maven to run robotframework test from maven project in eclipse:
[Robotframework Maven plugin](http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write user defined keywords in java which can be used in robot script, import "**AnnotationLibrary**".

Link is mentioned below and follow the steps [AnnotationLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/JavalibCore/wiki/AnnotationLibrary)
.

Answer (score -1):

try this way.
i am using python language to write test case. python is best way to write a test cases.

my test case file name is test_google_page.robot put this code to test_google_page.robot file and save it. next open command line and go to test_google_page.robot file path and run this command

```
[user@localhost google_test]$ pybot test_google_page.robot
```

then you can seen your test case result.

```
*** Settings ***

Documentation           your document
Library                 Selenium2Library


*** Variables ***
${Url}                  https://www.google.lk
${Browser}              chrome
${Delay}                3s

*** Test Cases ***
load google page
    [Documentation]     your test case document
    OPEN BROWSER        ${Url}     ${Browser}
    Input text          id=lst-ib   robot framework
    sleep               ${Delay}
    # click button        id=<button_id>            
    # Page Should Contain     loglevel=INFO  text=<content>
    Capture Page Screenshot     filename=test_result.png
    [Teardown]         CLOSE BROWSER
```