# How to open search box on web page using keyboard key (ctrl-f) in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to open search box using windows keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in selenium webdriver:

[image: How to open search box using windows keys ctrl+f in selenium webdriver]

Comment: Please click on my question to see the image to complete understanding my question.

Comment: You can use Robot class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670982/selenium-webdriver-how-to-use-robot-framework-with-java

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Explain better your problem and post your progress so far.

Comment: Andrei Suvorkov : Thanks for your help. If I will have been any doubt, then I will pin you.

Comment: Marc Estrada: Thanks for providing these beautiful guidelines. I would be kept in mind before any post the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium doesn't provide a possibility to simulate keyboard actions. But to be able to do it, you can use a [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class in `Java`.

You have not specified on which language are you developing. Thats why I have stored some useful links to different analogues of `Robot`:

1. For [Python](https://pypi.org/project/py_robot/)
2. For [C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library)

Comment: Andrei Suvorkov : I am using java.

Comment: Andrei Suvorkov : Thanks Andrei for your great help. Have a great day:)

Answer (score 0):

FIRST INSTALL PYWINAUTO BY  run pip install pywinauto in your python ide

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="PATH OF CHROMEDRIVER")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
SendKeys("^F")
```

Comment: got what ur looking for

Comment: You should mention in your answer that PYWINAUTO is applicable only for Windows (partially for Linux), so your solution won't work on other OS

Comment: bhupathi turaga : Sorry for I did not mention in my question, What language I am using. Actually, I am using selenium webdriver using java. So any guess in java? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, guys, I have found a solution, It is working fine for me, Thanks Andrei Suvorkov to suggest me read about robot class.

```
try {
       Robot robot = new Robot();

// Simulate a mouse click
       robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
       robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

// ctrl + F  

   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);

   // CTRL+F is now pressed 

   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

} catch (AWTException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```